# Repeat groups in regex replace

Tags: regex

I have a list of n numbers/words in each line, ex:

```
12
20
24
25
26
30
31
32
39
98
103
105
106
108
116
117
122
132
138
140
etc...
```

I want *with a single regex* put them in groups of n in each line, ex (n = 10):

```
12, 20, 24, 25, 26, 30, 31, 32, 39, 98, 
103, 105, 106, 108, 116, 117, 122, 132, 138, 140, 
etc...
```

I currently can do it in two replaces:

```
Match: /(\w+)\n/  ->  Replace with: "$1, "
Match: /((\w+, ){10})/  ->  Replace with: "$1\n"
```

But how to do it in one?

EDIT: No code allowed, only regex (match regex and replacement regex). If it matters, I'll be running this on sublime text 3.

Comment: As you're doing it on sublime text, maybe use another tool more adapted to this ? something like awk sounds more adapted to the task, i.e: `awk '{printf "%s, ",$0}; NR%10 == 0 {printf "\n"}' input_file`

Comment: @Tensibai Yes, I know. But it would be cool to do it with only one regex.

Comment: short answer, you can't, there's no way to do two processing within one regex. you can eventually capture by groups of ten, but you won't be able to do a conditional replacement depending if it's the 10th record or not :)

Comment: Sublime Text does not support Boost-style regex replacement. It is configured to use a PCRE-compatible replacement. However, even if you were to choose Notepad++, the pattern would be too long. Here is a S&R rule for just 3 items: `(?<a1>\d+)(?:\R+|\z)(?:(?<a2>\d+)(?:\R+|\z))?(?:(?<a3>\d+)(?:\R+|\z))?` -> `(?{a3}$+{a1},$+{a2},$+{a3}\n:(?{a2}$+{a1},$+{a2}\n:$+{a1})))`. For 10, it will be already very long. It is not possible to solve using `\G` or any other operator.

Answer (score 2):

I´m not sayng is pretty...

```
match: (\w+)\n(?:(\w+)\n)?(?:(\w+)\n)?(?:(\w+)\n)?(?:(\w+)\n)?(?:(\w+)\n)?(?:(\w+)\n)?(?:(\w+)\n)?(?:(\w+)\n)?(\w+)?
replace with: $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10
```

I have no idea how to capture the 10 groups in (\w+){10}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it fails if you have, for example, 13 elements.

Comment: thoug it will put the numbers, but still will appear like 
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \n
10,11,12, , , , ,